# Static html/css blog as firestore backend SEO optimization

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, static-libraries, firebase-hosting, static-html

Hi developers and support managers.

I'm trying to make a blog using pure HTML/CSS and JavaScript.
Here I've implemented a design [check readersmess](https://readersmess.web.app).

I just needs a guide which backend should I use to store my blog posts. I already tried to use firestore but my post was not indexing to google.
I was reading id from url to fetch data from firestore.

Kindly suggest me the best method. I don't want to move from firebase hosting. How can I use other libraries to store and fetch posts so that post should be indexed in google?

Answer (score 0):

To make your site discoverable, try to follow the basic steps that optimize your site for search engines (such as referrals on other sites, using descriptive titles, etc.) as described in the Google's [basics guide](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/basics/optimize-your-site).

After that, you can take an active approach in your URLs management and create and submit a list of your URLs (sitemap) to Google that can improve the discovery of your site:

> By providing our systems a direct list of URLs to your content, known
> as a sitemap, our ability to find your pages no longer relies solely
> on your page's relationship to other referring pages on the wider web.
> This speeds up the process of our systems discovering your content.
> Typically, you host the sitemap on your domain in a place accessible
> by Googlebot.

For the general overview and instructions on how to create and submit a sitemap, refer to the [Sitemaps guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/overview).